# Suppressionfilter doesn't work in checkstyle config file

Tags: java, checkstyle, suppression

Can anybody say why suppression filter doesn't work? It still generates javadoc errors for Candidate_ file.
checkstyle.xml
`...

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="C:/sts-projects/staffing4/trunk/config/suppressions.xml" />
</module>

<!-- Checks that a package-info.java file exists for each package. -->
<module name="JavadocPackage" />
```

...`

suppressions.xml

```
<suppressions>
<suppress checks="JavadocMethod" files="Candidate_.java" />
</suppressions>
```

Comment: How are you running this - standalone, from ant/maven/eclipse, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because `checkstyle.xml` above references `suppressions.xml` while the file mentioned below that is `suppression.xml`?

Comment: No, it's ok, it's only here mistake, file name is suppressions.xml